# MySQL error: Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I get the following error every time I attempt to run my script;

> Unknown column '3624dfaf5f3429fc' in 'field list'

Here is my script, well the parts that matter anyway;

```
$num1 = mt_rand(1, 2147483647);
$num2 = mt_rand(1, 2147483647); 
$valcode = dechex($num1).dechex($num2);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE valcode='$valcode'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed because ".mysql_error());
```

If I change `$valcode` to an integer (`$num1`) it runs fine. On the other hand, as a hexidecimal it leads to said error. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure that this is copied and pasted directly? That problem doesn't normally happen unless there are missing `'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that error comes from a different query where you did not surround the code with single quotes. That would result in the query being valid when it's an integer but not when it's a hex string not surrounded by quotes. A string without quotes is interpreted as an identifier (a column name or alias).

i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE valcode = 123
```

is valid, comparing `valcode` to the number 123,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE valcode = 3624dfaf5f3429fc
```

is not valid, as it tries to compare `valcode` to a column or alias named `3624dfaf5f3429fc`. I don't believe the code you shared can lead to that error message.

Comment: Very odd. Perhaps you could take a look at http://ideone.com/BlEL8, that's the entire code (around 22 lines). I honestly can't see what has invoked the erroer though.

Comment: There's no single quotes around `$valcode` in the `INSERT` query. That's the one producing the error, which you should've seen because "lolol" would be part of your error output.

Comment: That's why I added in the "lolol" somehow I managed to misread the error (probably because I'd loaded the page 10 times without it added - as in both queries outputted no error identifiers). Anyway, thanks a lot :)!